# Add views dynamically and get value from those views

Tags: android

I need help regarding adding new set of views and get value from those views.

In my example, I want to add 4 TextViews on Button click and open TimePicker from each view click and display new selected time on respective TextView.

Below is screenshot of view.

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Can you provide us some code that you have been trying? @LearnPainLess

Comment: set your text views in your xml file and set their visibility gone.. when you click button set them visible and in onClick you can set the functionality.

Comment: you can create the view easily in xml, to increase reuse you can use merge/include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these 4 views are fixed you could just create the xml and add them all to a single holder that you set invisible. If you mean by dynamic that it could be either 4 or 99 views, I'd recommend a RecyclerView. Plenty of [examples](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial) on the internet. If you create a recyclerview with a custom adapter it is very easy to get the respective data per view.

For the future, please add more context to your question like what you've tried, what the result was and why this isn't your expected result. This is a very broad question.

Comment: Yes i can make this using recyclerview, but i want another solution.

Comment: Thank u to clear my doubt, so i will got for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that on clicking the clock button under the time section (on the right) you would want to set the selected time into the text field. You can simply call view.getParent() on click of the button and from the parent you can get the first child i.e child at 0 and set the text into the text field. This will work provided the button and textfield are within the same layout.